# CS0426 The type name 'Factory' does not exist in the type 'Task'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual studio 2017 is showing me this error when accessing Factory property of Task's class. Please tell how to fix this error. The code is:

```
var t1 = new Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 1500));

private static void DoSomeVeryImportantWork(int id, int sleepTime)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task {id} is beginning");
            Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
            Console.WriteLine($"Task {id} has completed");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Task.Factory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.factory(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static property - you should use type name to access static members:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 1500));
```

Comment: Thank you for so quick respond. That was really stupid mistake that I should have discovered before posting. Big thank :)

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator isn't used to call methods. It's used to create objects. If you aren't trying to create a new object of type `Task.Factory` (which is not a type to begin with, as you learned), omit the `new` operator.

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 1500));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Factory` is a static property.Therefore you are supposed to use type name to access a static member.

```
public static TaskFactory Factory { get; }
```

You may want to have a look at `TaskFactory` class as well.

Also keep in mind that starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the Task.Run method is the suggested way to create a Task object with default configuration values.

```
var t1 = Task.Run(() => DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 1500));
```